# How to add table row having dropdown with dynamic data in Struts1.3

Tags: jsp, struts-1

I have an jsp page which displays single table row with 2 columns. One column is text box and other column is countryList dropdown which gets populated from actionForm. Now my question is can I add a row in table by clicking on "Add Row" button so that i can get the complete countryList in the dropdown of newly added.

I am not sure of this because clicking on "Add Row" button will call a Javascript method. While list will be populated from ActionForm (Server Side).

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the page for the first time, get the country list from the Struts action.

Keep that country list as array in the javascript. Psuedo code will be like

```
var countryList = {""<logic:iterate name="myForm" property="countries" id="country">
,"${country.name}"
</logic:iterate>
}
```